# how can i obtain a popup window when i click a button in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, uibutton, vaadin

I am developing a Ui. I was not able to proceed furter due to clicklisteners. How can i add a popup window when i click a button and in this popup i wanted to show some details. The following code i implemented is. I am using  vaadin Ui button having a vaadin version 7.6.3.

```
public Item(Domain name)
    {
    _view = new ItemView(); 
    _view.get_Button().addClickListener(new SayHelloClickListener());
.......
}

@Override
    public Component getView() {
        return _view;
    }

    public class SayHelloClickListener implements ClickListener {

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener#buttonClick(com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent)
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            _view.////what should i add here.??
    }
```

I am trying to display set of buttons in my Ui and if i click the button i wanted a window to pop up showing some details i add.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a popup window by creating a `Window` instance, configuring its contents and adding it to the `UI` instance that is the root of the component tree.

Expressed in code, this would be something like `_view.getUI().addWindow(new Window("Title", contentComponent));`.

Comment: Here is the [link to reference documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-sub-window.html#layout.sub-window.modal) in case Vaadin 8 is used.